# What's difference between @JoinColumn and @JoinTable in One-To-Many relationship?

Tags: database, hibernate, orm, annotations

I encountered Hibernate problem, What's difference between @JoinColumn and @JoinTable in One-To-Many relationship?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

JoinColumn  uses... a join column to map the asociation:

```
Order        Line
-----        ----
id           id
...          order_id (FK to order.id)
             ...
```

JoinTable uses... a join table to map the association:

```
Order        Order_Line                           Line
-----        ----------                           ----
id           order_id (FK to order.id)            id
...          line_id (FK to line.id, unique)      ...
```